# Synchronizing WaitOnAddress with WakeByAddressSingle

Tags: multithreading, windows-10-universal, c++-cx

I need a dispatch loop in C++/CX that takes tasks as input and dispatches them in a queue on a different thread. I managed a simple implementation that consists of the following:

```
void Threading::DispatchQueue::Add(TaskType task)
{
    // The scope causes the lock to be released before WakeByAddressSingle.
    // This mutex is used for synchronizing queue operations, so it shoudln't
    // be needed for WakeByAddressSingle.
    {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mux);

        GetQueue().push(task);
    }

    WakeByAddressSingle(&CompareAddress);
}

void Threading::DispatchQueue::Runner()
{
    while (true) {

        TaskType task = DequeueTask();

        if (task != nullptr) {
            task();
        }

        else {

            Log::LogMessage(this->GetType()->FullName, Level::Debug, "While is running!");

            // The scope guarantees that the lock is released before the thread is
            // put to sleep. It's noticeable that the thread must not sleep while
            // the lock is acquired, or otherwise the Add(TaskType) method can never
            // acquire the lock, meaning that the thread will never wake up.
            {
                std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mux);

                if (!GetQueue().empty()) {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            WaitOnAddress(&CompareAddress, &UndesiredValue, sizeof(CompareAddress), -1);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that queue operations on the two methods are synchronized by `DequeueTask`, as follows:

```
Threading::DispatchQueue::TaskType Threading::DispatchQueue::DequeueTask()
{
    std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(_queue_mux);

    QueueType & queue = GetQueue();

    if (queue.empty()) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    TaskType task = GetQueue().front();
    GetQueue().pop();

    return task;
}
```

This implementation has been working fine in most situations except when `Add` calls `WakeByAddressSingle` before the thread is put to wait. Take the following example:

1. The `Runner` acquires the mutex and checks whether the queue is empty. Lets assume it is. At this point, the block of code terminates and the lock is relinquished.
2. At this moment `Add` kicks in, acquires the lock, pushes a task to the queue, and calls `WakeByAddressSingle`. Notice that the `Runner` thread is not sleeping yet.
3. The `Runner` thread gets CPU time again and goes to sleep with `WaitOnAddress`.

As the task was already added and `WakeByAddressSingle` called, the thread never awakes until another task is added.

The problem is that I cannot acquire locks (I think?) before `WaitOnAddress` because if the thread goes to sleep with the lock then the lock will never be released. Is there some sort of paradigm that can be used in this situation? How do you synchronize `WakeByAddressSingle` and `WaitOnAddress`?

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to implement the *producer/consumer pattern*. It is well known and understood. But I still don't understand, why you are trying to roll your own (instead of using `IAsyncTask` or C++' co-routines).

Comment: That is correct. I also realize that semaphores can be used to solve this problem, I'll look into that now. The reason I'm not using `IAsyncTask` is because I do not control the thread in which they run. I need these tasks to be dispatched in order, and as such I'm creating a dispatch loop that takes control of the thread. The thread is not returned to the pool until the loop is terminated. Regarding co-routines, are you referring to boost? This project has a requirement not to include boost.

Comment: I was referring to the [experimental C++ feature](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental), which was [introduced in Visual Studio 2015](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2014/11/12/resumable-functions-in-c/).